# How to get additional records based on dates

Tags: spotfire

In my bar chart visualization, my value axis is:

```
UniqueCount([Case ID]) - UniqueCount([Case ID]) over (Previous([Axis.X]))
```

My category axis is:

```
BinByDateTime([Date],"Year.Month",1)
```

Is there any way to create a detailed visualization to show the additional `[case id]` for each month?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean the additional case id for each month?

Comment: yes. i would like to have a detailed visualization to show that but do not know how.

Comment: To show "what" exactly?  Are you trying to show the cumulative sum? Assuming your date is formatted DD/MM/YYYY then are you wanting to see 1 for Jan, 2 for Feb. 3 for mar... etc? Currently each month only has 1 case id that is uniquely different than the one before it. Thus, your formula and visualization represents this.

Comment: what i would like to implement is that when i click on the bar chart, corresponding additional case id will be selected.  for example when i click on April, case id 4 will be selected. however right now, all the case id in April will be selected

Comment: please post some sample data. From your question it's not clear